# highcharts - assign custom text using yaxis.stacklables.formatter to each bar

Tags: highcharts

I have 2 bars in my bar chart - bar1 and bar2
is there a way to assign custom text using yAxis.stackLabels.formatter property specific to each bar? Or please let me know if there is any other way to do this.
For ex: i want to say something like - if it is bar1 then the stack label text should be "label for bar1" and if it is bar2, it should be "label for bar2"

Please let me know if i didnt make myself clear enough.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` in the formatter callback has an `x` property (zero-based) indicating which bar it is.

So it's as easy as:

```
    yAxis: {
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return "Label for bar " + (this.x + 1);
            }
        }
    },
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6WV3S/).

Comment: Silly, i couldnt find it out, Thanks for your help!